# import GeneticAlgorithm ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libs.GeneticAlgorithm'

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I have been trying to run a code a found and I get this kind of error . I don't know how to deal with this because I am new to python and trying to understand the concept of TSP problem.
Any help would be appreciated
Code below

```
from libs.GeneticAlgorithm import GeneticAlgorithm

def main():
    poland = Country()
    poland.add([
        City('Gorlice', (49.655299, 21.159769)),
        City('Sosnowiec', (50.286263, 19.104078)),
        City('Łódź', (51.760229, 19.457209)),
        City('Wrocław', (51.108314, 17.037802)),
        City('Poznań', (52.406376, 16.925167)),
        City('Toruń', (53.013790, 18.598444)),
        City('Zielona Góra', (51.935619, 15.506186)),
        City('Szczecin', (53.428543, 14.552812)),
        City('Rzeszów', (50.041187, 21.999121)),
        City('Kraków', (50.049683, 19.944544)),
        City('Olsztyn', (53.770226, 20.490189)),
        City('Lublin', (51.245376, 22.568278))
    ])
    print('Cities:', end=' ')
    print(*(city for city in poland.cities), sep=', ')
    ga = GeneticAlgorithm(100, mutation_rate=0.5, ptype=Route, args=(poland.cities,))
    ga.run(seconds=10)
    fittest = ga.alltime_best
    best_fitness = fittest.fitness
    print('Best route:', fittest)
    print('Best fitness:', best_fitness)
    print('Generations:', ga.generation)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "found" this code (most probably on the internet?) then the one who posted this had a `libs` folder in his machine, with a `GeneticAlgorhythm.py` module in it, so you either find this GeneticAlgorhythm module, or you won't be able to run this code successfully.

When you see, in python `from baz.bar import Foo`, Python is going to look for the `bar` module into the `baz` folder, and import class `Foo` from it. So you need to have `baz` module on your PC, or else that error will appear

Answer (score 1):

It comes from this repository: https://github.com/reconndev/Genetic-Algorithm-TSP. In order to get it running, simply clone or download the repository. Then, in the main (root) folder, run `python TSP-Text.py`.

```
python TSP-Text.py 
Cities: Gorlice, Sosnowiec, Łódź, Wrocław, Poznań, Toruń, Zielona Góra, Szczecin, Rzeszów, Kraków, Olsztyn, Lublin
Best route: Toruń->Olsztyn->Łódź->Lublin->Rzeszów->Gorlice->Sosnowiec->Kraków->Wrocław->Zielona Góra->Szczecin->Poznań
Best fitness: 0.4219619417258425
Generations: 807
```